# How would I be able to cancel the asynchronous oledb query shown?

Tags: c#, oledb

I'm trying to cancel an asynchronous running oledb query. I've tried the cancellation token method, but couldn't get it to work. There doesn't seem to be any youtube videos or stack overflow questions related to cancelling oledb queries. Lot's of stuff on sql server queries but not oledb.

```
At the Global level:
CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

private async void btnQueryDatabases_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Disable the Query Button     
            btnQueryDatabases.Enabled = false;
            DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
            Waitform wf = new Waitform();
            wf.startUp();
            wf.Visible = true;
            wf.Refresh();

            try
            {
                if (chkIncludeDLabResults.Checked == true)
                {
                    string SQL = DLABSQL();
                    string connectionstring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=K:\R&D Dept\Development Lab\DLab Databases and Add Ins\DLab Results Database\Development Lab Results Database.accdb;Jet OLEDB:Database Password='xxxxxxxx'";

                    try
                    {
                        var dataTable = await Task.Run(() => RunDLAsync(SQL, connectionstring, cts.Token));
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        //MessageBox.Show("This query has been cancelled.", "Query Cancellation");
                    }                    

                    adgvDLabResults.DataSource = myTable;
                }

                wf.aTimer.Enabled = false;

                if (CombinedDT.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    adgvDLabResults.DataSource = myTable;
                    adgvCombined.DataSource = myTable;
                }
                else
                {
                    CombinedDT.Merge(myTable, true);
                    adgvCombined.DataSource = myTable;
                }

                int Records = adgvDLabResults.RowCount;
                tsLabel.Text = "Rows Returned = " + Records.ToString();
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("This query is being cancelled.", "Query Cancellation");
            }           
            finally
            {
                btnQueryDatabases.Enabled = true;

                DateTime endTime = DateTime.Now;
                wf.lblEnd.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
                wf.lblElapsed.Text = (endTime - startTime).ToString();

                DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Clicking OK Will Exit This Screen and the Query Time Screen Also.", "End of Query Run", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.ServiceNotification);
                if (result == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
                {
                    tpg.SelectedTab = this.tpgALAT;
                    tpg.SelectedTab = this.tpgSearchFor;
                    this.Refresh();
                    wf.Close();
                }
            }
        }

private DataTable RunDLAsync(string commandText, string connectionstring, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            try
            {            
                using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionstring))
                {                   
                    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                    {                       
                        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                        command.CommandText = commandText;

                        using (var dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command))
                        {          
                            connection.Open();                        
                            var dataTable = new DataTable();

                            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();

                            dataAdapter.Fill(myTable);
                            return myTable;
                        }
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return null;
            }
        }

private void cancelOperation_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     cts.Cancel();
}
```

I've tried to add the cancellation token in the DataTable RunDLAsync method, but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Can you show how you tried adding the cancellation token?

Comment: Sure, I've updated my original question code with what I tried.

Comment: Nothing? How can I solve this?

Comment: Look at the samples here. https://csharp.hotexamples.com/examples/System.Data.OleDb/OleDbConnection/OpenAsync/php-oledbconnection-openasync-method-examples.html